# $(n_1)^2 + ... + (n_k)^2 = 5^{m+k}$ for all integers m

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $k$ be a positive integer larger than 1. Show that for every nonnegative integer $m$, there exist $k$ positive integers $n_1,...,n_k$, such that $(n_1)^2 + ... + (n_k)^2 = 5^{m+k}$.

I'm thinkin induction, but I don't know what the base case should be.

Comment: @RossMillikan The question stipulates $k>1$.

Answer (score 2):

The base case is $k=2$.  You should be able to find a sum, valid for any $m$, with $k=2$.  It will be different depending on whether $m$ is even or odd.  Show that if you have a solution with a given $m$ and specific $k$, you have a solution with that $m$ and $k+1$.  The fact that $3^2+4^2=5^2$ plays into this.